# Why does this bring up new instance

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to create an notification that when clicked brings up a message in my application, then when the user clicks the back button, I want it to go back to my main screen.

The problem is right now it creates a brand new instance and all the former data gets lost. What am I doing wrong?

```
 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService("notification");
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, beerwarn.class);
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
 stackBuilder.addParentStack(beerwarn.class);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
 PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent
                                          (0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
 builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
        //Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("BAC Level Notice")
        .setContentText("Your BAC has dropped below Max Legal BAC")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beerwarn);
       //builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

 nm.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android: launchMode = singleTask` or singleInstance in your activity in the androidmanifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name="yourmainscreenActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion, when you bring up the message screen, clear every other activities.

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService("notification");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, beerwarn.class);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setContentTitle("BAC Level Notice")
    .setContentText("Your BAC has dropped below Max Legal BAC")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beerwarn);

nm.notify(1, builder.build());
```

On your beerwarn.class, overrride the onBackPressed function, check for whether your mainscreen activity is running, assuming is it named MainScreen.class, if not, launch it.

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo rti : taskList) {
    if (rti.topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
        if (!rti.baseActivity.getClassName().equals(MainScreen.class.getName())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("currentTab", getIntent().getIntExtra("currentTab", 1));
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

super.onBackPressed();
```